# how to modify a specific / custom attribute for a user in ldap without uid or cn but another unique attribute value

Tags: java, database, ldap

I have a functional requirement of reading a table of users from a database, locate the user on an ldap directory, update a custom attribute value in the directory with a value from a specific value I read from the database using Java. However matching the records with the database with those of ldap directory can only be made using another custom field value from the db table against another custom attribute in the ldap directory. I don't have the UID or anything like CN by the time I read the database.

How can I find a user in ldap doing a custom attribute value search and then modify another attribute of the user in this manner?

With the examples I find on Stackoverflow and/or other sources I cannot fulfil the requirement without knowing the UID of the user beforehand.

Comment: You need to do an LDAP query to find the unique cn= or uid= and then you can update the record.

Comment: actually it's not the unique uid or cn but the DN you need. Often the uid or cn is part of that but the unique identifier of an LDAP-entry is the DN. And without that you usually can't modify an entry.